# How to generate a responsive output from plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, customization, responsive

this question is regarding plugin development. I created a plugin for my WordPress website. That plugin has a shortcode. Short code containing a form, responsive image upload and preview, rotation and some custom options. The thing is that this form is responsive in my theme, because I write some media query responsive, and this form is actually working good in the fullwidth template.

(1)How to make this plugin output is responsive in another theme also?

(2)How can I use bootstrap in this, because if theme didn't support bootstrap then I need to all it separate, &if theme support bootstrap I don't need to call it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin can add additional css (and javascript) files into generated pages. Functions `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` with proper parameters should make it work. To not load Bootstrap more than once, use `wp_style_is()` function. You can find more in [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is).

Comment: that i know . But how make it responsive with other theme ?

Comment: You bring your own bootstrap files and before registering end enqueueing just check, whether there is not other bootstrap files already registered. Function `wp_style_is` is there for that. I will update my response.

Comment: ok thank you . Please update . But i have other doubt in some theme instead of registering new style using wp_style_is() they are calling the style in theme header . What about this case.

Comment: There is no simple solution for this case. I think the best way is to inform theme author, tell him that he is doing it in wrong manner. Or send pull request. But you can't save the world. My advice is to use as small piece of Bootstrap as possible and don't care too much about it.